# (GetElement)Clicking a button with no ID, TAG, NAME, CLASS, VALUE, SIBLINGS

Tags: excel, vba, web

I'm trying to automate a web entry process. I need to get this button to click, but as the title says, it has nothing for me to go off of. This is literally what I'm working with. Anyone have any suggestions?

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMWx.png)

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://ww3.somewebsite.com/somePortal/processItem.do?action=openItem&userId=someUser"

IE.document.getElementById("filterfields").Value = "EVT_CODE"

IE.document.getElementById("filtervalue").Value = "9477474"
```

Comment: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://ww3.loweslink.com/VendorPortal/processWO.do?action=openwo&userId=dgibsd"'

Comment: Do a `getElementsByTagName("img")` then loop over the collection until you find an element where the `src` contains "dpsrun_out.gif", then click that element.

Comment: Thanks Tim. i didn't use it for this one, but I did do something similar for another element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. Sorry for the terrible formatting of the question, it was the first time. To help others in the future.....

This is what I did at first. It was my band aid fix.

```
ie.document.getelementByID("filtervalue").select
"SendKeys{ENTER}"
```

This highlighted my input value and just pressed enter. If you are new to VBA and need something to be immediately functional, just use .select and SendKeys and come back to it later.

then, 1 week later, I figured out

```
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("setUserIDAndRunDataspy();", "JavaScript")
```

This, on the other hand just literally runs the event itself and is more reliable.
In case you run into any issues, the first iterations I tried were something like

```
Call ie.parentWindow.execScript("setUserIDAndRunDataspy();", "JavaScript")
Call ie.document.execScript("setUserIDAndRunDataspy();", "JavaScript")
```

They didn't work for me, but worked for other scripts i checked. I'm not sure why though.

Another solution you could try to though I haven't tested it is what Tim Williams suggested. It would go something like this:

```
For Each ele In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("img")
              If InStr(ele.Value, "./images/dsprun_out.gif") > 0 Then ele.Click
Next
```